# How to get Session data in table on other page in PHP

Tags: php

i have this in $_SESSION

```
[56cb5bcf88754] => Array ( [make] => Honda [model] => sport [year] => 2015 ) [56cb5be9cc8c7] => Array ( [make] => hyundai [model] => elentra [year] => 2016 ) )
```

how can i access this session information on other php page by id?

Comment: id? you mean a $_SESSION['id']?

Comment: [56cb5bcf88754] is  unique id

Comment: did you generate this id ([56cb5bcf88754]) or is it a session id?

Comment: i genrerated by uniqid()

Comment: it's an array. you access things in it like you would with any OTHER php array. just because it's `$_SESSION` doesn't mean it's different somehow. $_SESSION is an array, like all other arrays. what makes it special is that php (may) auto-save/reload its contents when your script exits/starts.

Comment: Store the session unique id to another session same time you save the same id with vehicle information and then extract it when you require by using for loop.

    $_SESSION['uniqueid'] = uniqid();

Answer (score 0):

The problem isthat you are generating a random id and you can't retrieve it, right?

You should, then, store those ids in a location you know. For example:

```
$_SESSION['generated_ids'] = array('id1', 'id2');
```

Then you can access the other idexes based on the stored ids:

```
foreach($_SESSION['generated_ids'] as $id){
    var_dump($_SESSION[$id]);
}
```

*Consider that 'id1' and 'id2' used in this example are values generated by uniqd()*

Comment: i can not find how to get access with the generated id..i knew about array but couldn't get how to use that generated. i saved it in $_SESSION[$guid]=array( "make" => $_POST["make"], "model" =>
        $_POST["model"], "year" => $_POST["year"]);